# Elegant Asp.Net MVC 3 custom membership wrapper class with extended (custom) methods and properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, custom-membershipprovider

I am attempting to write a custom membership class.  It seems to work ok inhering the Membership class and providing functions for all the included required items (validate user, create user, delete user, isapproved, etc).

However, where I run into a problem is when I try to add properties or methods.

As all the other properties and methods are public override classes in a sealed class, 
the additional properties do not show up.

Say for example (example only, not "real" code):

```
public sealed class Membership : MembershipProvider
{
    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get
        {
            return "myApp";
        }
    }
    public string myValue { get;set;}
}
```

Now, I understand why myValue will not show up when I try to do Membership.myValue but Membership.ApplicationName will.

My question is, how to extend membership to show the custom items?  Do I ditch Membership.xxx entirely and write a wrapper class?  If so, how?  I can find all the documentation in the world on how to create a custom membership class.  I've got a working custom membership that works fine if I use all the available options only.  I've got a custom roles provider and a custom config section to store everything and it's best friend.

What I don't have is an elegant solution.

I'd like the end result to be that I use one reference (such as Membership.xxx or myClass.xxxx) to reference all membership items + custom items.

Please provide examples of how to implement or links to appropriate items that will resolve the custom methods item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you reference the membership instance you will just have to cast it to your class type, that's all.

Comment: I know it's that simple.  But for whatever reason, my brain just will not wrap around the fix.  Does that mean simply that every time I reference membership.xxxx I instead do a call to (myclass)membership.xxxx

Comment: yes - only if you want to access those custom properties otherwise just use membership.xxx of course : )  It may be cleaner using a static class of your own that wraps the calls to membership and use that instead so you aren't casting everywhere unless you only use those custom props in a place or two.

Comment: public sealed class Membership : MembershipProvider
{
    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get
        {
            return "myApp";
        }
    }
    public string myValue { get;set;}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) if you don't want to cast back and forth your instances